# Модем MTS ZTE MF-192 и Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: zte, ubuntu

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как заставить работать 3G модем ZTE MF-192 в среде Ubuntu 11.10? При подключении модема он определяется, загорается зеленый светодиод. Операционная система предлагает настроить соединение. Но после настройки система не может осуществить соединение.

Comment: Спасибо. Проблему решил самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1):

Его должен обработать usb_modswitch после чего он станет /dev/ttyUSB* , а дальше нетворк манагер тупо apn прописать логин и пас

Comment: Все так и есть. В настройках соединия прописан и APN, и логин, и пароль. Но при  попытке соединиться ссистема сообщает об ошибке "Modem Network: соединение разорвано"

Comment: либо провайдер  либо опции ppp /etc/ppp/ точно не помню там нужно лишнее выкинуть